# Colocar imagens com css em mediaqueries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo um site em bootstrap e ao colocar a logo ele somente funciona no html e não no css, mas o que acho estranho é que sómente a logo não funfa, já todos os estilos esta de boa!

**arquivo HTML**

**arquivo CSS**

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {    
    .navbar-brand {
        width:      150px;
        height:     150px;
        background-color: yellow; /* somente para debugar */
        background-image: url(imgs/logo.png);
}
```

Comment: Precisaria do seu html para poder fazer uns testes.

Comment: Há um erro de sintaxe, fecha as chaves da classe...

Answer (score 0):

Verifica onde está a imagem e onde está o seu arquivo CSS, dependendo de como estão dispostos os seus arquivos, o link do CSS e do HTML serão usados de formas diferentes.

Para acessar arquivos que estão em pastas anteriores você deve usar a notação `../`

**Você tem essa estrutura:**

```
seu-projeto/
    index.html
    imgs/
        logo.png
    css/
        style.css
```

**Para acessar a imagem do HTML ficará:**

```
imgs/logo.png
```

**Já do CSS, o link será esse:**

```
../imgs/logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você queira que a **imagem** da sua logo seja responsiva eu lhe aconselho adicionar uma `.img-responsive` classe à `<img>` tag. Assim a imagem será então escala bem para o elemento pai se ajustando aos tamanhos de telas.

Veja maiores informações na documentação oficial http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Um exemplo real para maior entendimento.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid"></div>
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"width=200px" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/About/Index">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/Contact/Index">Contacts</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```